# javaFXML PathTransitionproblem

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I have a question.
I am learning JavaFX and I would like to use the javaFXML. The only problem is, I have a little problem with a pathTransion.
You need a Node for the pathTransition, but I want to use a rectangle which is made in the SceneBuilder.
I gave the rectangle an fx:id and I used that one, but when I want to use this into mij node it says it needs a node and not a rectangle and it can't transform the rectangle into a node.
How can I resolve this problem?
Thank you already, if someone needs more information just ask and i will give it.
Thank you already for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your imports.

Are you sure you are using a [javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/shape/Rectangle.html)?

A `javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle` extends from `Node` so, it is a `Node`.

My guess is that you are mistakenly importing and using some other rectangle type, for example [java.awt.Rectangle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html).

If your problem is not import related, then, edit your question to include an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), so that somebody can replicate your issue.

Comment: I used java.awt.Rectangle and that was the error, thank you very much!